# Testing an Android application failed in Eclipse using Appium

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, appium

I wanted to learn about a tool to test Android application. After a bit of googling I came around this wonderful tool called **Appium** which is used to test Android application and also is an open source. I wanted to learn about it. So I went ahead and created a simple android application having few button clicks to start with the testing.

I have done all the following:

1. Plugged in all the necessary jar's into **Eclipse** IDE.
2. Downloaded and installed Appium server.
3. Plugged in `Maven` and `TestNG` for **Eclipse**.
4. Successfullly installed `SampleApp.apk` into the **Emulator**.

I next created a `TestNG` class to test the `SampleApp.apk`. The code for which is pasted below. However on running the application I received `java.lang.NullPointerException`. It's been two days. I tried doing everything, building, cleaning, restarting eclipse, creating a new application, re installing all the dependencies. But still I receive the same exception. I had referred the video by [Execute Automation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPnAm8R4LKA) and have done the exact same minus the application which is different in my case.

```
package com.example.appium;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestJavaAppium {

    AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void Setup() throws MalformedURLException{

        DesiredCapabilities capability =  new DesiredCapabilities();
        capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Emulator");
        capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.example.sampleapp");
        capability.setCapability("avd", "Emulator4.2");         
        driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4273/wd/hub"), capability);
    }

    @Test
  public void simpleTest() {

      Assert.assertNotNull(driver.getContext());
  }
}
```

My Appium is configured as below just to assure I had all the information correct.[image]

Ideally the code should run and launch the application (at least it did in the video) successfully. But what I received instead was the below exception:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\KC\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-518994855\testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED: simpleTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.appium.TestJavaAppium.simpleTest(TestJavaAppium.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:821)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1131)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:773)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:623)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@6d9c638: 225 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@7fbe847c: 230 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 26 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@5e265ba4: 14 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@2401f4c3: 14 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@182decdb: 12 ms
```

Where I possibly might have gone wrong to anger my Eclipse?

Comment: Your code looks like good,can you put some wait to launch application

Comment: Can you provide some more capabilities to Appium server like activityName of app . `capa.setCapability("appActivity", ".LauncherActivity");`  Change the activity name according to your app .You can take look of sample program @ http://mylearningdiaree.blogspot.in/2015/06/appium-sample-demo-program-of-android_11.html

Comment: appPackage and appActivity need to be provided for Android app to launch through Appium.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks good. Provide the app activity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `APP_PACKAGE`, you can set up Appium using the .apk full path in your PC:

```
capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/full/path/to/app.apk");
```